# Dot product of a tangent vector and the gradient

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate the dot product of a tangent vector and the gradient of $f$ at $(0,3)$. Anyways I found the tangent vector at $(0,3)$ which is $\langle-3, 0\rangle$ and then I found the gradient of $f$ at $(0,3)$ which gave me an answer of $\langle-2, 2\rangle$. So am I just suppose to do $\langle-3, 0\rangle \cdot \langle-2, 2\rangle$ to get my final answer? I ask this because an answer of $6$ does not really make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the tangent vector to the level curve/set at (0,3), then the tangent vector is perpendicular to the gradient. Thus, their dot product should be 0.

If you mean a tangent vector to the surface at (0,3), there are infinitely many tangent vectors that lie on the tangent plane, but the issue is they are of dimension 3 so you can't dot them with the gradient.

Comment: Thats a good point sadly it does not say if its to a surface or to a level curve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if everything is defined as you said, your answer is correct. Maybe I could help you more if you told why 6 doesn't make much sense